# Bootstrap form validation for only one field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have a simple form which consists of a email field and password field like follows

```
          <Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                    <Form.Group controlId="formEmail">
                        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="email" onChange={this.emailValidator} placeholder="Enter email" required />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId="formPassword">
                        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="password"placeholder="Password" required />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Button type="submit" size="lg" variant="light">
                     Login
                    </Button>


         </Form>
```

I want to include bootstrap form validation to the email field when the user starts typing the email address and the valiadation to the password field when submit button is pressed.

My approach was as follows.

```
handleSubmit = event => {
        const { loggingUser } = this.props;
        const form = event.currentTarget;
        event.preventDefault();
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            const loggingData = {
                "eMail": event.target.formEmail.value,
                "password": event.target.formPassword.value,
            }
            loggingUser(loggingData);
        }
        this.setState({
            validated: true
        })
    };

    emailValidator  = event =>{
        const form = event.currentTarget;
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
        this.setState({
            validated: true
        })
    }
```

But when i start to type in the email address field both the validations trigger and show the red border. How can i trigger the bootstrap validation for the email address only when the user starts entering the email address.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this bootstrap form and some js and do not forget to include Bootstrap css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```js
(function() {
            'use strict';
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('f-validation');
            var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            }
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }, false);
            });
            }, false);
            })();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


            <div class="container mt-2">
                <form class="f-validation" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                            <label for="validationCustomUsername">Email address</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Username"
                                aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Please enter valid email id.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                            <label for="validationCustom03">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" placeholder="Password" required>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                Please enter password.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="" type="checkbox" value="">
                            <label class="">
                                Remember me.
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Submit form</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```